# Yik Yak type user model and sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ip

I'm building an anonymous user model in rails, with each user distinguished by IP address.  There's no signing up or logging in per se. (Let's say it's a Yik Yak clone). I'm trying to figure out how to scaffold the user model and then how to establish a session based on IP alone.  How does this work? Does rails automatically know how to work with "ip" if i include it in the table when scaffolding?

```
From http://www.yikyakapp.com/legal/
Yik Yak does maintain a log, however, of the following information for each message posted:
 - The IP address from which the message was posted; 
 - The GPS coordinates of the location from which the message was posted;
 - The time and date when the message was posted.
```

Comment: You should ask a specific question about a single problem that you are encountering. Right now, your question is too broad, which is not for this site. Also, refrain from tag-bloat: this question has nothing to do with tags `user` and `ip` and probably very little with `postgresql`.

Comment: all that information is relevant

Answer (score 0):

If each instance of your app can only ever have a single user, try the following. Put this in your `users_controller.rb` file:

```
cattr_accessor :current_ip
```

In your application controller add:

```
before_filter :set_current_ip

protected
def set_current_ip
    User.current_ip = request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
end
```

Comment: Thanks, would I include just a column of "current_ip" in the user model then?

Comment: Exactly right. Then you can use that as the basis of your session.

Comment: Great, how do I save each user though?